# How does GitHub's Gist embed work?

Tags: github, syntax-highlighting, gist

Let's suppose that I have a file named my_python_code.py, and I upload it to GitHub's gist. Now I embed that gist into my blog, using the code provided by GitHub on the corresponding page.

When I browse my blog and I check the source code for the page, I discover that:

- the embed code calls a js file which performs some DocumentWrite commands, inserting the appropriate html tags (with css styles) on my page, and
- the associated css file is linked to my page. This file contains css declarations for 'gist' class as well as other classes.

This is all very nice. But I wonder: **starting from the same my_python_code.py file, what would I have to do to end up with the same final html code?**

I've tried using pygments and rouge (via pygmentize and rougify commands) with reasonable options but none of them highlights the original code using 'gist' tags (among others) as is done when performing the GitHub embed.

Comment: I’m really not sure what you are asking. Do you want to build such an embed system yourself, or do you still want to consume GitHub’s services in some way. What are you attempting to do?

Comment: @poke: Thanks for your answer. I'm trying to make some code in my (statically generated) blog look exactly as the gists that I (ocassionally) embed using GitHub's great gist embed service. And when I say *exactly* I mean not only *the looks* but also the html tags involved. But besides this, I'm just learning, so even if I never get to do it myself, I would very much like to know how such thing is done by GitHub (I'm assuming here that the algorithms/codes involved are open to the general public). Thanks again for your prompt response.

Comment: Well then first of all you need a syntax highlighter that formats your code with HTML. And then you should just tweak your syntax highlighter’s styles to match the look of Gists. Don’t go the other way (trying to generate an output that is exactly as GitHub’s output) but just change the style of the generated output.

Comment: Yes, but that solution would only be temporary, right? Because once GitHub changes their html tags on the embedded code, I would have to tweak mine. And it just feels like reinventing the wheel, doesn't it? Me, on this side, trying to discover what they did so that I can make those same changes in my code. My guess is that there's some syntax highlighter involved (either pygments, rouge, linguist, or some other I know not of) but also some syntax highlighting *style* which provides for the html tags  particular to the gist style (and which give classes such as 'gist', 'code-blob', etc.). Thx!

Comment: No, it wouldn’t be temporary since you would build a solution that is completely independent from GitHub. You only emulate their visual appearance but are in no way dependent on them, so any change on their side does not affect you.

Comment: Well it's not the search of independence that drives my question or interest, because I still use (and plan to use them in the future) gist embeds on my site. I'm trying to achieve this so that the jupyter notebooks that I post are also formatted in the same way. Nevertheless, my question stands: **starting from the same my_python_code.py file, what would I have to do to end up with the same final html code?** Or better still: what is it that GitHub does?